# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below code on list comprehension.

```
x = 2
y = 3

[x*y for x in range(x) for y in range(y)]
```

This is giving me below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    [x*y for x in range(x) for y in range(y)]
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    [x*y for x in range(x) for y in range(y)]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

However, below code works.

```
[x*y for x in range(x)]
[0, 5]
```

Is there any scoping rule for the second `for` loop in list comprehension?

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: the possible duplicate post does not talk about UnboundLocalError and scoping rule for list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Good question,however this code works well in `Python2.x`,and it will throw `UnboundLocalError` in `Python3.x`.

> It can be a surprise to get the **UnboundLocalError** in previously
>   working code when it is modified by adding an assignment statement
>   somewhere in the body of a function.

This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a **scope**, that variable becomes **local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope**. Since it assigns a new value to x, the compiler recognizes it as a **local variable**. Thus the earlier variable attempts to print the uninitialized local variable and an error results.

See more details from [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).

Comment: Ok that means for loop does have a local scope in list comprehension? As per my understanding for loop does not create any local scope when created at module level.